# Doctrine 2: Return related objects as array

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a User entity, that has a many to many relation with a **Tipo** entity.

I have the method to retrieve the related entities already working, so assuming `$u` is my user, `$u->getIdtipo()` returns all the wanted related objects.

Now, the result of the function above is a collection, but i need an array, since i want to return it as a json to my call.

I tryed to apply the `->toArray()` as well to the result of `getIdtipo()`, but the result of that operation is that it creates an **array** of **Tipo** objects, while i need an array of array.

Is possible to convert the collection of object returned by `getIdtipo` to a json, or an array of array?

Note: i would like to use the `getIdtipo()` instead of making a custom query to retrieve the same results.

---

**answer**

As from marked answer, i implemented a serializer, and used it.

From symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), i run `composer require symfony/serializer`

Than I created in my main controller a function that serialize, that's what i did:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

public function serialize($data, $format){
    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    return $serializer->serialize($data, $format);

}
```

and then simply return the user's *tipo* doing

```
$this->serialize($u->getIdtipo(), 'json'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way would be to implement [`JsonSerializable`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.jsonserializable.php) on `Tipo` like:

```
class Tipo implements \JsonSerializable
{
    // ...

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'some key' => $this->someValue, // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

this, paired with the `ArrayCollection::toArray` should be enough.

---

Other than that you can use some sort of serializer, e.g.:

- http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it and  [that](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)'s what i did. I'm updating my question to show the answer. Btw, serializing the whole Collection, is not needed the `toArray`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`?

You could do something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(array(
    'data' => $u->getIdtipo()
));
```

Then you can return the response:

```
return $response;
```

If not, then you can make use of the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle). Once installed you can do something like:

```
$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
$serializer->serialize($data, $format);
$data = $serializer->deserialize($inputStr, $typeName, $format);
```

Comment: Doesn't works neither. it returns `{"data":{}}` as before. Moreover there's a typo in your code, after `'data' => $u->getIdtipo();` remove the `;`